# Covert int to hex string with a specific format in python

Tags: python, unicode, hex

I need to print a range of unicode characters given in hex.

```
range = "<range first-cp="0030" last-cp="0039"/>"
```

I need to write a code in python, that takes this string `range` as input and prints all the code points in the range `0030` to `0039`. I have come to know that I will need to convert each code point to an `int` first then increment it and convert it back to a `hex` string. For example, if

```
first_cp = "0030"
second_cp = int(first_cp, 16) + 1  # converts it to an integer and increments it
second_cp = hex(second_cp)  # returns '0x31'
```

Here, I don't know how can I convert the integer back to a `hex` string such that it has the format `0031` instead of `0x31`. Please note that I do not want to remove `0x` from the string only.

Comment: [`format(48, "04x")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: So basically you want a zero-padded hex string?

Comment: seems like the first_cp has what you need but you're overwriting it.

Comment: I can have a code point `0673`. Using the method I described in the question, I get back `0x673`. In this case, I do not want `x` in the string.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question to make clear that I am having difficulty in converting my integer string back to a hex string.